Remove rename from hyperlink in Google Sheets
I have a Google Sheet with a bunch of links in it. I don't want to look at ugly urls so I have them renamed to simply say "Link". However I can't preview the links like this. I haven't been able to find a way to do this at all. I want to find someway to see just the link without the rename. I know I can just Ctrl+K to remove the rename however I have over 400 cells I need to do this for. I also don't want to need to do any complex programming or need to open each individual link.
I've tried looking everywhere to be able to find something to do this and everything either doesn't work and I just get an error or a blank cell or it requires doing some really advanced programming. I don't care how this gets done. Whether it is being able to see a preview when I hover over the cell, whether I need to write some mini = code and copy and paste that into another program to be able to hover over it. Whatever lets me easily see a preview of the link that I can easily do 400 times.

You can use this formula:
=HYPERLINK(B1, "Link")

In the above formula, B1 is the cell that has the actual URL.
Create a new column for the updated links, enter the formula in the first cell, and then drag it down to the 400th cell. This will generate the new hyperlinks as needed.
Sample Output

